# iPhone: Multiple call for viewWillAppear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my iPhone app `viewWillAppear:` gets called.

Then `wiewWillDisAppear:` gets called.

And then `viewWillAppear:` gets called again.

So what could be the reason for `viewWillAppear:` to be called after `viewWillDisAppear:`?

Here in my case problem is that I am setting the value for flag in "nsuser defaults" before this page loads and checking the value for the  flag  on current screen appears

and i am resetting the value for flag on    `viewWillDisappear`

during the execution of  `viewWillAppear` of  current page  the cuntrol reaches to some anther page and returns to same page and flag Resets

what should I do to maintain my flag value so it reset only once on final   `viewWillDisAppear`?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks

Comment: Any chance we can see some code?

Comment: you'll get multiple calls for both of those events generally speaking that is normal.  what is the real problem here?

Comment: And tell us what was happening when these were called - I doubt that they just got called at random, I expect that the app was doing something at the time . . .

Comment: I have edited my question so please see it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many reasons. Simply don't rely on the order / number of calls to viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear. It's also a very bad idea to abuse "view...Disappear" as a clean-up/destructor method because it is not called in all circumstances.

It is however almost always safe to assume viewDidAppear gets called after a viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that the view reappears.